# Merging two datasets in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, piglet

I have a pig script in which I am loading a dataset, diving it into two separate datasets and then performing some calculations and finally adding another computed field to it. Now I want to join back these two datasets.

```
A = LOAD '/user/hdfs/file1' AS (a:int, b:int);

A1 = FILTER A BY a > 100;
A2 = FILTER A BY a <= 100 AND b > 100;

-- Now I do some calculation on A1 and A2
```

So essentially, after the calculation, here is schema for both:

```
{A1 : {a:int, b:int, type:chararray}}
{A2:  {a:int, b:int, type:chararray}}
```

Now, before I dump this back to HDFS, I want to merge the two data sets back. Something like `UNION ALL` in SQL. How can I do that?

Comment: On a different note, you can optimize the script by using SPLIT (https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT) in place of FILTER.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UNION should work for you - but your original schema does not match the output shown (b is loaded as a chararray and later on becomes a int) - i'm assuming this is a typo.

If the tuples have fields in differing orders, you can use the ONSCHEMA keyword when performing the UNION:

```
A_MERGED = UNION ONSCHEMA A1, A2;
```

**EDIT** Link to the PigLatin docs for [UNION](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#union)

Comment: Oops. Mistake. Corrected it now.

Comment: In which case you don't need the ONSCHEMA keyword when performing the UNION.

Comment: What is the significance of ````ONSCHEMA````?

Comment: From the UNION docs: `Use the ONSCHEMA clause to base the union on named fields (rather than positional notation). All inputs to the union must have a non-unknown (non-null)`. So without it if the two sets had the same field names, but in different orders you'd get wierd results

Answer (score 0):

You could use SPLIT

```
SPLIT A INTO A1 IF a > 100, A2 IF a <= 100 AND b > 100;
A = UNION A1, A2;
```